# OpenCV libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-confif Error in Raspbian Buster

Tags: raspbian-buster, opencv, raspberry-pi-os

History,
I have been running OpenCV on Raspbian Stretch in a virtual environment for a couple of years.
Due to the requirement to add functionality for a PS4 controller I switched to Raspbian Buster.
I re-installed OpenCV 4.5.1 (opencv-contrib-python) using the PyImageSearch pip guide [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/19/pip-install-opencv/)

Now, I have been tryinig to run some of my known working OpenCV python programs, remote headless using vncserver and vncviewer (Mac) and with a monitor and kbd attached, but keep getting the following error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /tmp/pip-install-hyt7ii05/opencv-contrib-python_3f506ec0b739451b84e2498020092625/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:651: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

Any ideas on the correct way to solve this - I understand I need to install libgtk and pkg-config, but want to do it correctly.

Comment: start with `apt install libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config` - basically, if something suggests you "install" something, `apt install something` is pretty much the way to do it "correctly" (raspberry pi OS is Debian based)

Comment: Yes, but then it says "re-run 'cmake'"?

Comment: `or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'` - I take it neither of those things mean anything to you?

Comment: No sorry, don't know how to configure cvShowImage?

Comment: Any one else have any ideas on how to resolve this? It seems there is a problem with Buster and OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

After you install `libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config`, you need to uninstall then purge  your previous version of opencv: `pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python` then `pip cache purge`. For me, that was the issue, python kept rebuilding the old version. You can then reinstall: `pip install opencv-contrib-python`